# How to see executable content under AIX

Tags: c, executable, aix, objdump, nm

I have a question about executables and C.

If you had to know the content (the version of each .c file written in a commentary) of an executable BUT you just have the executable, you don't have the sources. How do you proceed ?

I've seen the "nm" command, cuting what I want with "cut" I can have in output the .c files but I can't read the versions inside because I don't have the source files.
I've also seen the "objdump" command but I can't try it under AIX (of course ...) is there an equivalent? Is this possible with objdump to know what I want to?

Thx for your help and attention :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'version of a .c' file?

Comment: With SVN when I have compiled my version of the executable, I want to recover the versions of .c files linked in the executable.

Comment: Neither the compiler nor the linker knows or cares about SVN versions (the same goes for RCS/CVS)

Comment: I know, but I wanted to say that the number of the file's version (it's linked to SVN then) will be written inside of the .c file. You may be see what I mean now ^^

Comment: define a char array with the contents of the $version variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent command for objdump in IBM AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546846/what-is-the-equivalent-command-for-objdump-in-ibm-aix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do what I wanted to. Using the '#pragma comment(user, "comment")' line (I didn't knew this one) it writes at compilation and link this "comment" in the end of the binary file, so I include this line on each .c file. With a the parsing of the executable, I'm able to recover the versions of each files with only the binary.

Thanks for your help again and your time :) .

Comment: (Hopefully you won't forget updating this "comment" in your files. I know I would.)

Comment: You can parse the executable with `strings my_exe_file`

Comment: Walter A, I tried but the last line who contains the commentary isn't recognized as a "string" and it does not works, I already tried ^^ then I put symbols at the begining and the end, I cat -v , tr the symbol as '\n', grep the lines with the pattern "VERSION_OF" (it's always written in the comment). That's how I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get source back from a compiled executable. There is a variety of information you can get from it though. For instance, you can get the size of the `data`, `bss`, and `text` sections (through the `size`) command. You can also install the Linux utils for AIX which will give you more tools that can shed light on your executable (see [What is the equivalent command for objdump in IBM AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546846/what-is-the-equivalent-command-for-objdump-in-ibm-aix)). Recent AIX binaries are in a format called XCOFF64 or XCOFF32 (both have good articles on wikipedia).

Comment: The configuration control system, like SVN, will still have the original source available as a specific version.  if that version is available within the object/executable file, then it is easy to go to SVN and request that specific version.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing the **what**(1) and **ident**(1) commands, used to find file versions embedded as strings in an executable.

Those strings, containing `@(#)` or `$Id`, were inserted into source code files by the version control systems, SCCS and RCS, of olden times.